# How to define an index for the child table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, indexing, hibernate-mapping

I ran into a situation. The below defines a parent and a derived child from parent. Since parent has `@Table` annotation i can defined index. But since there is no `@Table` annotations in child how can i defined index for that child columns. I thought using `@SecondaryTable` annotation but than i think `@InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` is useless since another child tables will be created. Please correct if i am wrong somewhere. Also if there any solution for child indexing problem.

```
@Table(name = "Parent", indexes = {@Index(name = "IDX_USERNAME", columnList = "username")})
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE")
@Entity
public class Parent{
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("C")
public class Child extends Parent{
}
```

Comment: You define the index in the Table annotation of the Parent class. There is a single table, and that's where it's defined.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is there no way i can define index on child class. Just curious since it helps in code understanding and looks cleaner

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible. A much better idea would be to use FlywayDB or Liquibae to define your schema anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it, is to use the Hibernate specific [@Index annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Index.html):

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "CHILD_NAME_IDX", columnNames = "name")
private String name;
```

This annotation is **deprecated**, but you can apply it to fields or methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually i saw this deprecation and than i thought might be there is some other annotations provided by Hibernate so thats the reason thought of asking here )))

Comment: The JPA equivalent is not applicable to fields, so it's not strictly identical.